# icCube: downloading from IDE throws gwt exception

Tags: iccube

icCube IDE throws an exception when trying to export and download documents from the server.

The IDE pops up a DOWNLOAD ERROR:

`fileIoError: Invalid response: HTTP ERROR: 500 Problem accessing /icCube/service.gwt.download. Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException: Name is null Powered by Jetty://`

What is the meaning of the `Name` variable here?

Logs:

```
[  qtp1960554990-1154] [DEBUG] (12:03:37.864) [R] FILE_D 22186 servlet-started
[  qtp1960554990-1154] [DEBUG] (12:03:37.865) [R] FILE_D 22186 servlet-done
[  qtp1960554990-1154] [ WARN] (12:03:37.865) /icCube/service.gwt.download
java.lang.NullPointerException: Name is null
        at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:236)
        at crazydev.iccube.gwt.base.shared.model.file.GwtFileType.valueOf(SourceFile:15)
        at crazydev.iccube.gwt.server.service.IcCubeFileDownloadServlet.doHandle(SourceFile:119)
        at crazydev.iccube.gwt.server.servlet.IcCubeHttpServlet.doGet(SourceFile:28)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
        at crazydev.iccube.server.http.IcCubeServletHolder.handle(SourceFile:63)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1669)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:83)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:364)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at crazydev.iccube.server.authentication.IcCubeGwtAuthenticationServletFilter.doFilter(SourceFile:101)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:221)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:497)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: What kind of file are you trying to download ?

Comment: icc-schema files.

Comment: downloading a icc-schema from the doc panel ?

Comment: it's working on our computers, really looks as you've special settings. Are you directly acessing icCube server or using some kind of proxy, firewall or similar in the middle (between the browser and iccube) ?

Comment: Yes, there are multiple proxies in the middle. Just tried to access icCube directly and it's working fine. It will be an issue with our network and not icCube. Thanks.

Comment: can you delete this post ? not sure it's really helpful ..